# Spring Boot application does not load spring.factories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I initialized a new project with Eclipse Spring boot and created the spring.factories file under src/main/resources/META-INF. On startup the configured bean does not get loaded.

Spring.factories:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
net.conjur.config.ConjurConfiguration,\
net.conjur.config.ConjurPropertySourceLocator
```

My application class got some annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

As an example one of the beans looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConjurConfiguration {
@Bean
public ConjurPropertySource getConjurPropertySource() {
return new ConjurPropertySource();
}
}
```

I already tried this:

1. moving the META-INF folder in the project into different places, but without any luck.
2. I tried to load the file from the main Application using the resource loader, but also no success

Comment: What versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud are you using?

Comment: This is a short part of my pom:
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.5</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

the rest of the POM does not have any other version mentioned.

Comment: For `BootstrapConfiguration` to work, you need to be using Spring Cloud.

Comment: I use the spring cloud as a dependency:
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
Isn't this enough?

Oh sorry, I missed a dependency and a version:
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>

Comment: Is that the right approach, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing of Bootstrap configuration is disabled by default in Spring Cloud 2020.0 and later. To re-enable it, set `spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true`.

Comment: What is the new and better way to enroll a Bean in the startup?